# Merging 2 tables that contain duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables here

Table r

```
    id        |add       |jid  |sid|cocode
    ------------------------------------------
    0234567890|PO BOX 456|p123a|2  |TRAVEL2000
    0234567890|PO BOX 789|q456b|4  |TRAVEL2000
    0234567890|PO BOX 123|r789c|1  |TRAVEL2000
```

Table o

```
    jid  |pkey      |tid|date      |cid
    ---------------------------------
    q334a|0234567890|1  |15/08/2013|200
```

and I would like to create a new table that consist of the merging of both table o with table r with the intention of getting the tid, date and cid information by using the id = pkey and I want the cocode to be unique. The problem is I wouldn't be able to use the jid to do the matching in order to pick which record as the output as they might be different as the example I shown above. So I am thinking to get the latest jid (in this case r789c) by using ascending order. My expected result table will be:

```
    id        |add       |jid  |sid|cocode    |tid|date      |cid
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    0234567890|PO BOX 123|r789c|1  |TRAVEL2000|1  |15/08/2013|200
```

I am using SQL Server 2008, any solution will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with common joins. Syntax and examples found http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html.  Once you struggle for a bit, post what you've tried and we can help!

Comment: Thanks for that. I have managed to play around with it and get what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to join the last record from `r` (based on jid) with the corresponding record from `o`.  If so, then the following query would do what you want:

```
select r.id, r.add, r.jid, r.sid, r.cocode, o.tid, o.date, o.cid
from (select r.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by jid desc) as seqnum
      from r
     ) r join
     o
     on r.id = o.pkey and seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create the corresponding table to hold that data. Then, insert the result of this query into it:

```
SELECT r1.*, o1.tid, o1.date, o1.cid FROM r r1
LEFT JOIN r r2 ON r1.id = r2.id AND r1.jid < r2.jid
JOIN o o1 ON r1.id = o1.pkey
WHERE r2.jid IS NULL
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e211/1).

PS: Note that "the latest jid" I understand it, based on your example, that it is actually ordered alphabetically.